# Hard sound transition when animating

Tags: audio

I'm doing a 3d (currently stereo) sound animation. For that i'm using a simple speaker at the origin and i'm moving the camera (listener) by hand. Whilst simultaneously recording keys on the timeline.

The sound volume goes down with the radius which is expected and ok, but the angle works fine except in the case where the camera approaches the symmetry axis at the meeting point of the left and right speaker (in my case of top-down view that would be the y axis; x+ is oriented towards right). When the listener camera crosses it one of the speakers suddenly goes off and the other turns on accompanied with a loud transition click. I'd like that to be smooth.
Can somebody please help me out? What other info can i provide?

[image: Blender setup]